# How do I select rows from a table that do not have corresponding rows in a related table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two MySQL tables:

- `alerts`
- `alerts_viewed`

Alerts is a table that contains basic information about alerts, and the `alerts_viewed` table contains information about the viewed alert (by user id and alert id):

The fields on `alerts_viewed` are:

- id
- alert_id (FK to alerts table)
- user_id (FK to users table)
- is_hidden

Basically, I know that if I wanted to select only rows from alerts that have a corresponding row in `alerts_viewed`, I could do an INNER JOIN. I just do not know how to do it the other direction.

How do I select all rows from the `alerts` table that DO NOT have a corresponding row in the `alerts_viewed` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    alerts a
        LEFT JOIN alerts_viewed b
            ON a.alert_id = b.alert_id
WHERE   b.alert_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from alerts
where id not in (select alert_id from alert_viewed)
```

or

```
select a.* from alerts a
left outer join alert_viewed av on a.id = av.alert_id 
where av.alert_id is null
```

Comment: Wouldn't that result in two queries?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from JW and Juergen's answer I would like to propose one more way with

**NOT EXISTS**,

```
select * from alerts aa
where not exists
   (select alert_id 
   from alert_viewed av
   where av.alert_id=aa.id
   )
```

Comment: Excellent idea, except that the syntax is wrong: the subquery should be correlated to the outer query : `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM alert_viewed av WHERE a.id = av.alert_id )`

Comment: Sorry for correcting you. The idea was axellent but the syntax was not right.

Comment: It's my pleasure bro. I will not make this mistake again. This is co-related query. Now I understood how it works..